# what is the difference between notification node and data node in FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I had read that not to add notification node in the body of the request, and I tried to send without notification node but it seems that the message not received but when I add the notification node it work well

So, **what is the difference notification node and data node in Firebase cloud messaging?**

```
{
    "to": "/topics/some_topic",
    "data": {
        "key_1" : "some_value",
        "key_2" : "some_value"
     },
     "notification":{
        "body" : "some_message"
     }
}
```

Is there any link to doc I can read ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` node is used for sending notification if the application is on the background/foreground and in some phones if it is also killed.

The `notification` node is used for sending notification if the application is on the foreground. If it is in the background you wont receive the notification.

The best option I found is to use `data` node alone.

Also it is explained very well in this link: [The FCM messages types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Answer (score 2):

**Notification node** (a.k.a Notification messages)

When sent, this will receive a notification on the device, regardless of whether the app is in foreground/background/terminated state, but the notification will be shown only when the app is not in foreground. You can bundle a data payload with this of upto 4 KB. The upside is that you do not have to worry about generating a notification every time, the libraries take care of that. The downside is that there is **no way** **not to show** the notifications, for eg when you want to do something silently.

**Data node** (a.k.a Data messages)

When sent, this will fire up all the same callbacks as a normal notification node would, the only difference being that a notification won't pop up on its own, you are the master of your own callback! This is useful for when you want to do something silently, like refresh the cache, update the database etc. As a data node will have the data payload and will fire up a callback at any state of the app, you can generate a notification on your own and fire it up. This gives you the freedom to **design** your **notification** however you want!